# Webpack Externals require not defined with Electron and Angular 4

Tags: angular, webpack, electron, externals

I have a setup with **Webpack**,**Electron**, and **Angular 4**. I searched and tried several approaches, however as I could not solve it, i am going to ask here.

When i run webpack, it compiles without errors, however in the browser's console i get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.128 (external "require('fs')":1)
```

I tried to include it in several ways:

```
let fs = require("fs");
```

I had the same issue with path, child_process, etc.

My **webpack.config.js** defines externals:

```
module.exports = {
    "externals": {
        "electron": "require('electron')",
        "child_process": "require('child_process')",
        "fs": "require('fs')",
        "path": "require('path')",...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Is solved it. Since all Node functions are already provided through the Webpack externals, one does *not have to require* them but **use them via imports** like this:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

You can read more on the solution [in my article](http://www.matthiassommer.it/programming/exceptions/webpack-require-not-defined-solution/).